# Использование кавычек с "ура"

Tags: кавычки

Подскажите, нужно ли заключать в кавычки "ура" в следующем предложении?

*Поприветствуем его троекратным ура.*

В интернете видела варианты: *троекратное "Ура!", троекратное "ура", троекратное ура.* Но не могу найти правило.
Как все же правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)

> **УРА, *межд*.** 1. Боевой клич войск при атаке. *Атакующие кричали "ура". Над полем боя гремело "ура".* // Клич воинов, выражающий одобрение чего-л., восторг по поводу чего-л. *Войска крикнули "ура" генералу, принимающему парад.*

[***На ура***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) в значении наречия пишется без кавычек (ответы Грамоты.ру).

[***Ура***](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1069614) в значении существительного: «Далече грянуло ура: полки увидели Петра» (Пушкин).

Правило действительно трудно найти. В Вашем предложении я бы не стал использовать кавычки, но не думаю, что кавычки были бы ошибкой.